# How to create a memory leak in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I was just wondering how you could create a system memory leak using C++. I have done some googling on this but not much came up, I am aware that it is not really feasible to do it in C# as it is managed code but wondered if there was a simple way to do this with C++? I just thought it would be interesting to see how much the system suffers because of code not being written properly. Thanks.

Comment: It is very feasible in C#. A common cause is people that believe it is not feasible and don't worry about it.

Comment: Haha! Born to be wild! :) The not so practical answer would be: just write a moderately sized C++ program and it'll have memory leaks :) (just jocking)

Comment: What's a "system memory leak", as opposed to any other kind of memory leak? Do you mean that you want to create a leak that persists beyond the lifetime of the program? That can happen if (and only if) some implementation-defined API lets you do something that consumes kernel resources indefinitely. For example you could start a daemon process or similar. Even that's not strictly "leaked", since it's still accessible via the process list and could be killed later.

Comment: @Steve I just meant a memory leak in general really, someone edited to a better question title already

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A memory leak occurs when you call `new` without calling a corresponding `delete` later. As illustrated in this sample code:

```
int main() {
    // OK
    int * p = new int;
    delete p; 

    // Memory leak
    int * q = new int;
    // no delete
}
```

Comment: So presumably that would leak memory once as the new int is still in memory, if that were in an infinite for loop then it would leak until the program has been killed?

Comment: If it were an infinite loop then it would leak an "infinite" amount of memory (until the system hangs or forcibly kills the process).

Comment: @StackedCrooked So is this the only way a memory leak can happen in C++. (Sorry I am a C++ beginner).

Comment: @Supertecnoboff There are many ways in which memory leaks can happen. Just keep learning :)

Answer (score 27):

1. Create pointer to object and allocate it on the heap
2. Don't delete it.
3. Repeat previous steps
4. ????
5. PROFIT

Comment: creating a pointer isn't enough. It has to point to a heap-allocated object (and even then, the pointer isn't really important)

Answer (score 16):

```
int main() {
    while(true) new int;
}
```

Comment: Ah, true enough. I was focused on C#; The OP's requirement to have it in C++ is not really necessary. But, it's ok to answer in C++, of course

Comment: why not simply while(new int); ?

Comment: @Luchian: A pointer allocation as boolean condition? That's not simple or clear at all.

Comment: @sehe: The question is how to create a leak in C++- why the hell would anyone answer in C#?

Comment: @DeadMG: Because it sucks to do it in C++ only because it is believed to be impossible in C#? _`I am aware that it is not really feasible to do it in C# as it is managed code`_ is just false information.

Comment: To leak memory even quicker, replace `new int` with `new char[N]`, where `N` controls how quickly you leak memory.

Comment: @sehe: True. But that's still not actually the question.

Comment: @DeadMG are we supposed to be clear in designing our memory leaks? :D Also, it is simple... new int returns a pointer which can be evaluated to a boolean...

Comment: @DeadMG: no offense, I said it's ok to answer in C++! My comment was wrong, way too quick and ... deleted

Comment: @Luchian: If you design something in, it should be clear. And it's not simple because that's not exactly a normal use of `new`.

Comment: IT CRASHED MY COMPUTER! Rebooted and everything's fine. That was amazing.

Answer (score 8):

There are many kinds of memory leaks:

- Allocated memory that is unreleasable because nothing points to it.
  These kind of leaks are easy to create in C and C++. They are also pretty easy to prevent, easy to detect, and easy to cure. Because they are easy to detect there are lots of tools, free and commercial, to help find such leaks.
- Still-accessible allocated memory that should have been released a long time ago.
  These kinds of leaks are much harder to detect, prevent, or cure. Something still points to it, and it will be released *eventually* -- for example, right before `exit()`. Technically speaking, this isn't quite a leak, but for all practical purposes it is a leak. Lots of supposedly leak-free applications have such leaks. All you have to do is run a system profile to see some silly application consume ever more memory. These kinds of leaks are easy to create even in managed languages.
- Allocated memory that should never have been allocated in the first place.
  Example: A user can easily ask Matlab to creating these kinds of leaks. Matlab is also rather aggressive at creating these kinds of leaks. When Matlab gets a failure from `malloc` it goes into a loop where it waits for a bit and then retries the `malloc`. Meanwhile, the OS frantically tries to deal with the loss of memory by shuffling chunks of programs from real memory into virtual memory. Eventually everything is in virtual memory -- and everything creeps to a standstill.

Answer (score 3):

Just write an application which allocates "a lot of data" and then blocks until it is killed. Just run this program and leave it running.

Comment: Why would you use malloc in C++ ?

Comment: Why use C++ to make a two-liner which leaks? I'm fixing my answer to use 'allocate' instead of malloc.

Answer (score 3):

```
class ClassWithLeakedMemory{
private:
    char* str;
public:
    ClassWithLeakedMemory(){
        str = new char[100];
    }

    ~ClassWithLeakedMemory(){
        cout<<"We are not freeing the dynamically allocated string memory"<<endl;
    }

};


class ClassWithNoLeakedMemory{
private:
    char* str;
public:
    ClassWithNoLeakedMemory(){
        str = new char[100];
    }

    ~ClassWithNoLeakedMemory(){
        cout<<"We are freeing the dynamically allocated string memory"<<endl;
        delete[] str;
        str = null;

    }

};

int main() {
    //we are creating an automatic object of the ClassWithleakedMemory
    //when we will come out of the main, this object will be
    //out of scope. hence it will be deleted. so destructor will
    //be called. but in the destructor, we have not specifically
    //deleted the dynamically allocated string.

    //so the stack based pointer object str will be deleted but the   memory  
    //it was pointing to won't be deleted. so we will be left with an
    //unreferenced memory. that is memory leak.
    ClassWithLeakedMemory objectWithLeakedmemory;
    ClassWithNoLeakedMemory objectWithNoLeakedmemory;
    return 0;
}
```

The way the stack based pointer object refers to the dynamically allocated memory in both the classes can be shown pictorially as below:

[image]

Comment: So "You don't just want any memory leak, you want a _fancy_ memory leak, right? "
No.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, just use P/Invoke to allocate a lot of memory, resource handles and keep them around.

You can use unmanaged code just fine in a simple C# harness

Comment: See the article referenced by [witty-bear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242493/how-to-create-a-memory-leak-in-c/7242569#7242569) for excellent demonstration of this

Comment: What about garbage collection it will remove all those allocated memory after end of code block

Comment: @Dr.MinaMounir only for garbage collected heap references.

Comment: Thanks for clarification ... the article i was reading at time of question was just talking about delegate to be garbage collected and not the allocated memory i misunderstood it

Comment: @sehe He asked about **C++**, not C#

Answer (score 2):

When an object that is created using `new` is no longer referenced, the `delete` operator has to be applied to it. If not, the memory it occupies will be lost until the program terminates. This is known as a *memory leak*. Here is an illustration:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void memory_leak(int nbr)
{
   vector<int> *ptrVector = new vector<int>(nbr);
   // some other stuff ...
   return;
}
```

If we return without calling `delete` on the object (i.e. `delete ptrToVector`) a memory leak occurs. To avoid this, don't allocate the local object on the memory heap but instead use a stack-allocated variable because these get automatically cleaned up when the functions exits. To allocate the vector on the run-time stack avoid using `new` (which creates it on the heap) and the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as:⠀⠀⠀

```
new int;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){

for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)

double* ptr = (double*)malloc(1000000*sizeof(double))

//free(ptr);

ptr = NULL;

}
```

note : the hashed line of code caused a memory leak while the process allocated it and did't return it back to the OS

Comment: Does this mean the memory is reduced? I mean does memory allocated to app and not returned to OS never be available to be used by other apps?