# Allocating memory - Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, destructor, rule-of-three

I want to know when or if I have to delete this object.
Here is the constructor of a basic class Object
Object.cpp:

```
Objects::Objects{
    Obj one = new Obj;
    Obj two = new Obj;
}
```

I know when allocating memory you are supposed to delete it at some point, but I have allocated memory in the constructor and want to use the variables one and two again. When do I delete them?

Comment: Typically you will delete them in the corresponding destructor (in this case, `~Objects`.)

Comment: those are local objects, hence you should delete them before you leave the constructor, because otherwise any reference to them is lost and you have a leak. Having said this, most likely you do not need any pointers, and most certainly you do not need to use `new` (and I suppose you actually wanted to initialize members, but thatss not what the code does, please clarify)

Comment: Maybe you don't want to use raw pointers and instead you wanted std::unique_ptr<Obj>. Also are you sure you want to create local objects in the constructor?

Comment: `Obj one = new Obj;` would be a bug. `one` is not a pointer. Maybe you wanted `Obj one;` but I question why you want to create local objects that don't exist after the constructor is done.

Comment: @drescherjm sorry for going a bit offtopic, but a way to make this legal is when `Obj`s constructor takes a pointer to an `Obj`. THough even then one shouldnt write code like this imho

Comment: Good point. I did not consider it because its an odd way to do things.

Comment: try to use the search engine here, you will find many useful references about pointers,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointers?tab=Votes and 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655065/when-should-i-use-the-new-keyword-in-c

Answer (score 4):

To make it simple, anytime you make a `new`, you should make a corresponding `delete`.

In your case, you have to delete the allocated objects `Obj` at latest before your objects `Objects` are deleted, which means in the `destructor` of `Objects`, which also means that you have to keep a way to access to the `one` and `two` pointers at the destructor (one way might be to make them as a member of `Objects`). Your current case fails to do so because `one` and `two` are local variables and are not pointers.

It may look like the following:

```cpp
class Objects
{
public:
  Objects();
  virtual ~Objects();
private:
  Obj* one;
  Obj* two;
};

Objects::Objects{
    one = new Obj;
    two = new Obj;
}

Objects::~Objects{
    delete one;
    delete two;
}
```

There are some rules you need to be aware of, when coping with resource management and it is the [rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) which will guide you to create robust code in terms of resource management.

Another remark:
It might be better to use [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) as even with the approach I mentionned in my post, if an exception or a crash  happenned before your code executes the `delete` lines, you would still have a memory leak as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372242/example-of-memory-leak-in-c-by-use-of-exceptions)

Comment: This will also leak memory if `new Obj` throws an exception. And that is why you should always use smart pointers or container classes. Never try to do `new`/`delete` on your own. You will most likely mess it up. But even better, when possible (as in this case), you should just inline the object.

Comment: Thanks for your review, I agree with you concerning smart pointers. Howver I provided this answer and did not talk about `smart pointers` because the original question was `I would like to know when and if I need to use delete` and he provided a similar example. I add your remark in my response.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know when or if I have to delete this object.

If you allocate with `new` and don't deallocate, then you leak memory.

> I have allocated memory in the constructor and want to use the variables one and two again, when do I delete them ?

If you want to initialise variables in constructor and use them later, then you should use non-static member variables instead of automatic variables in the constructor.

If you were to allocate memory in constructor, and point to it with a member, then typically you should deallocate in the destructor. For more information, see Resource Acquisition Is Initialisation idiom. However, you should not use bare owning pointers, and you should not use dynamic allocation unnecessarily. Here is a simple example that I recommend as your first option:

```
struct Objects {
    Obj objects[2];
};
```

Comment: fyi, I made an attempt to fix OPs question, but my edit was not in sync with your answer. If you feel like you can rollback my rollback ;)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I wouldn't assume that OP is aware of the distinction between initialising an automatic variable, and initialising a member variable in the constructor, so the "fix" may be confusing. With the type being wrong as well, it's hard to guess either way.